# Json response error handling

Tags: ios, json, swift

My app has a search bar that sends a query to a MySQL database and then receives a JSON response and displays it in a view. This works great when the response is success (there's an actual array and rows in MySQL). However, when the response is empty I would like to display an alertbox with a simple error.

My PHP code on the server is set to echo `No rows` when the query response is empty, how can I achieve this in my app?

This is what I have going right now:

```
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    if(searchBar.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        return
    }

    doSearch(searchBar.text!)

}

func doSearch(searchWord: String)
{
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    //created NSURL
    if let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_coffees) {
        //creating NSMutableURLRequest
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        //setting the method to post
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        //getting values from search bar text field
        let searchText=mySearchBar.text
        //creating the post parameter from search bar text field
        let postParameters = "searchQuery="+searchText!;
        //adding the parameters to request body
        request.HTTPBody = postParameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in
            //exiting if there is some error
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                self.displayAlertMessage(error!.localizedDescription)
                return;
            }
            //parsing the response
            do {
                guard let coffees = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray else {
                    //Doesn't exist, or isn't an NSArray
                    return
                }

                var newcoffees=[face]()

                for coffee in coffees {
                    //getting the data at each index
                    let coffeeName = coffee["name"] as! String
                    let coffeeDirectLink = coffee["calculation_toemail_"] as! String
                    let coffeeImage = coffee["calculation_toemail_"] as! String

                    let newface = face(name:coffeeName,
                                       directLink: coffeeDirectLink,
                                       image:coffeeImage)
                    newcoffees.append(newface)
                    //displaying the data
                    print("name -> ", coffeeName)
                    print("direct_link -> ", coffeeDirectLink)
                    print("image -> ", coffeeImage)
                    print("===================")
                    print()
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.faces = newcoffees
                    self.collectionview.reloadData()
                })

                 let errorMessage = newcoffees["No rows"] as? String
                if(errorMessage != nil)
                {
                   // display an alert message
                    self.displayAlertMessage(errorMessage!)
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()
    }
}

func displayAlertMessage(userMessage: String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But what's going on is I'm getting an `Cannot subscript a value of type '[face]' with an index of type 'String'` where I tell it what the error response is. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: `newcoffees` is a array of `face`, while `newcoffees["No rows"]` suggests that it's a dictionary. That's why you are getting the error message. Could you show the json when there is that now row message? Instead of "no rows", you may want the JSON to respond an empty array, and then just check if `coffees.count == 0`?

Comment: Larme I think checking for JSON response count equalling to 0 is the way to go, how would I achieve that?

Comment: It seems that you understand how you can JSON parsing. So, try start by logging the JSON when it's empty. Check then that specific case.

Comment: Will do, I'll log an empty to NSLOG and work from there, thanks for the count idea.